# How can I assign a variable to a value in a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, csv

I'm working with a csv for a class project.  It's got 3 columns, "year", "title_field", and "value."  In trying to solve a bigger problem, I just want to be able to assign a variable to a specific value, depending on the year and title field.

The csv looks like this:

```
2008,Total Housing Units,41194
2008,Vacant Housing Units,4483
2008,Occupied Housing Units,36711
```

Here's the code I have:

```
import csv

ohu = 'Occupied Housing Units'
vhu = 'Vacant Housing Units'
thu = 'Total Housing Units'
filename = 'denton_housing.csv'

# creates dictionary
with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    housing_stats = []
    for row in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=','):
        year = int(row['year'])
        field_name = row['title_field']
        value = int(row['value'])
        denton_dict = {'year': year, 'title_field': field_name, 'value': value}
        housing_stats.append(denton_dict)

if row['year'] == 2008 and row['title_field'] == vhu:
        vac_unit = int(row['value'])
        print(vac_unit)
```

I ran the program with a print statement without the if statement at the bottom and it gave me the entire csv data as a list of dictionaries, which is what I wanted.  However, when I changed it to what it is now, it just runs and doesn't print anything.

For instance, there is one row that will match the year and that particular title field.  I'm trying to assign the value in that row to `vac_unit`

Comment: There's an indentation error in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your indenting of the code in question is wrong. Please update if so.

```
for row in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=','):
    year = int(row['year'])
    field_name = row['title_field']
    value = int(row['value'])
    denton_dict = {'year': year, 'title_field': field_name, 'value': value}
    housing_stats.append(denton_dict)

    if row['year'] == 2008 and row['title_field'] == vhu:
        vac_unit = int(row['value'])
        print(vac_unit)
```

You are comparing an integer to a string.

```
if row['year'] == 2008 and row['title_field'] == vhu:
```

should likely be

```
if row['year'] == '2008' and row['title_field'] == vhu:
```

or

```
if int(row['year']) == 2008 and row['title_field'] == vhu:
```